# Контроль перенаправление на сайт

Tags: php, html, telegram-bot, telegram, html-form

Необходимо добавить функцию в бота телеграмм , который имеет связку с html сайтом на контроль перехода с сайта . А именно , когда кликают по любому переходу на сайте , поступает уведомление в боте , с выбором на какой сайт перевести , и при клике пользователя переводит на необходимый сайт . Так же необходимо что бы была возможность изменения информации на самом сайте , с бота . Например есть на сайте заголовок и рядом него при заходе на сайт пользователем я с бота мог отправить любой текст .
Либо если есть возможность направьте на похожие статьи , а то уже ищу больше полугода...

Бот написан на пхп , без бд .

Comment: Переходы в бота и другие события на сайте, тебе придется на js-е отслеживать и самому обрабатывать, а вот редактировать что-то на сайте из бота, то это уже более реально, но схема будет примерно следующей: у тебя есть тг-клиент, он шлет запрос на сервер, а сервер уже разруливает по правам доступа, если можно, то что и как изменить на сайте.

Comment: @Borislav Но на сколько я понял , для того что бы сервер мог в любом случае просматривать возможность изменения , необходимо делать базу , без нее не сможет удерживать . Или все таки есть возможность?

Comment: База 100% необходима, но разумеется, никто не мешает вам использовать какой-нибудь файл, но если по нормальному, то БД. У меня есть реализация бота с MySQL: https://github.com/Borislavv/Translator-telegram-bot и Mongo: https://github.com/Borislavv/remote-executer правда они оба на Go, но возможно, вам поможет чем-то.